# Missing links in force directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I'm using [Modifying a Force Directed Graph II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0adcc447925ffae87975a3a81628a196) as a base for my graph. I thought I'd coped with the different ways we're handling how links are formatted (Bostock's uses references, mine uses strings), by changing

```
simulation.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(200))
```

to

```
simulation.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
}))
```

but no dice. The links still aren't being drawn. What else am I missing?

[My jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/qd1dsque/3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors in the code you posted in your question:

1. When modifying the link force in your code you are no longer providing the links to the force since you are not providing `links` as an argument. It has to be `d3.forceLink(links)`.
2. The function provided to [`.id()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_id) is the accessor function to the nodes' ids. In your case the id of a node is defined by its property `name`. Thus, you need to change the accessor to `.id(function(d) { return d.name; })`.

Change the definition of the link force to the following to make it work:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}))
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
nodes = [{
  name: "test",
  type: "test"
}, {
  name: "test2",
  type: "test2"
}];
links = [{
  source: "test",
  target: "test2"
}];

var width = 500,
  height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  color = "blue";

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY());

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"),
  link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
  node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

forceGraphUpdate = function() {

  node = node.data(nodes);
  node.exit().transition().attr("r", 0)
    .remove();

  node = node.enter().append("circle")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color;
    })
    .call(function(node) {
      node.transition().attr("r", 8)
    })
    .merge(node);

  link = link.data(links);

  link.exit().transition()
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
    .attrTween("x1", function(d) {
      return function() {
        return d.source.x;
      };
    })
    .attrTween("x2", function(d) {
      return function() {
        return d.target.x;
      };
    })
    .attrTween("y1", function(d) {
      return function() {
        return d.source.y;
      };
    })
    .attrTween("y2", function(d) {
      return function() {
        return d.target.y;
      };
    })
    .remove();

  link = link.enter().append("line")
    .call(function(link) {
      link.transition().attr("stroke-opacity", 1);
    })
    .merge(link);

  simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);
 
}

function ticked() {
  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

forceGraphUpdate();

function addNode() {
  nodes.push({
    name: "test",
    type: "testing"
  });
  forceGraphUpdate();
}
addNode();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```